# My app is invisible for some LG devices on play store

Tags: android

Hi I developed an app and I cant show it on play store if the device is a LG Optimus 2x. If I search it on the web it says incompatible. Any ideas?

The device runs a 4.0.4 custom ROM and in Market model name says: "Yoigo LGE LG-P990"

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="-"
android:versionCode="-"
android:versionName="-" >

<!-- Sdk min-max -->
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<!-- Multi-screen support -->
<supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true"/>

<!-- Google tv -->
<uses-feature android:name="com.google.android.tv" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>

<!-- Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<!-- Permission configuration required by Scoreloop -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="AppApplication" >
    .....

</application>
```

And my project.properties:

```
target=android-15
android.library.reference.1=../PATH/TOLIB
```

Comment: Which version of Android does the phone run?

Comment: sorry I edited the main post, it runs a custom 4.0.4 rom and the correct model name is "Yoigo LGE LG-P990"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the modified density LCD on build.prop.